# Postgresql data value only years

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to set value of onl year(without months and days) like 2005, 2001 in Postgresql if data type is Date?

Or should I use other variable types?

How can I set default month/day in postgres?

Answer (score 1):

you can't set a part of a `date` individually. You could however do something like this:

```
update the_table
   set the_date_column = to_date('2005'||to_char(the_date_column, 'mmdd'), 'yyyymmdd');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT to_date('2005','yyyymmdd')
```

but if you want to store only year than integer is more suitable and preferred.

Comment: some times it can be 2005-05 sometimes 2005-05-05 sometimes 2005. I think your solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would cause syntax error:

```
select date '2014';

-- ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "2014"
-- SQL state: 22007
```

You can use 1st of january in all of your inputs, but if you want to store only the year, [`integer`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) is more suitable.